# HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable [IIS 8]

Tags: iis-8

I am using IIS 8 in my PC,in browser when i **type localhost** IIS 8 Page is opened, but when i try to **give my IP address instead of Localhost, for ex.122.16.1.30**,
I am getting the following error,
**Service Unavailable
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.**
I don't know what is the problem.
Any ideas??

Comment: Maybe your IIS is configured only to accept connections to local addresses? (subnet 127.*.*.*)

Comment: But its working fine in remaining ports like 8083,8085 and all for example when i type this "122.16.1.30:8083" in browser, IIS 8 Page is opening fine, but when i try to open in browser with "122.16.1.30:80", IIS 8 page is not opening,what will be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

i fixed that issue,by uninstalling the IIS and install it again .